# Facebook Graph API (upgrade v2.10 to v3.10)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an old Facebook application (v.2.10) for retrieve campaigns results, has stopped to work.

I get error after upgrade version to > 3.10.

[image]

This is my app code, comparing api code get from Graph Api tool is same.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
  'app_id' => 'xxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.20',
  'default_access_token' => 'xxxxx',
 ));

try {

 $response_active = $fb->get(    'act_1646241562297916/insights?fields=ad_id,ad_name,adset_name,reach,cpc,ctr,clicks,spend&time_range={"since":"2017-01-01","until":"2020-03-31"}&filtering=[{"field":"ad.effective_status","operator":"IN","value":["ACTIVE"]}]&level=ad&limit-1'
 );


} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} 

$graphEdge_active = $response_active->getGraphEdge();

//Convert JSON string to Array
$myArray_active = json_decode($graphEdge_active);

?>

<table class="rnr-c rnr-cont rnr-c-grid rnr-b-grid rnr-gridtable hoverable " cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
      <tr class="rnr-toprow style1 ">
      <th class="rnr-gridfieldlabel" style="text-align: center;">ad_id</th>
      <th class="rnr-gridfieldlabel" style="text-align: center;">spend</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
 <?php 

 foreach($myArray_active as $results_active){    
          echo "<tr class=\"rnr-row style1 \" id=\"gridRow5\">";     
          echo "<td class=\"rnr-field-text\">" .$results_paused->ad_id."</td>";

          echo "<td class=\"rnr-field-text\">" .$results_active->spend."</td>"; 
          echo "</tr>";
 }

?>
```

Comment: 4 versions later there are sure to be changes. Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/, starting with v2.11 to see what has changed since your previous implementation and update accordingly.

Comment: `'default_graph_version' => 'v3.20'` - there is no API version `v3.20`. I am not sure whether the SDK uses this value to create the API URL dynamically, but if it does, this should fail, because it creates the wrong URL then. `v3.2` would be the correct here.

Comment: I changed to 'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2', but get same error.